# trying to sort a vector of objects with a comparison operators

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, vector, stdvector

i'm trying to implement a cards game and i'm using a vector of cards.
I implemented every comparison operator there is with the hope that the 'sort' function will sort according to those operators, but I always get that ace is the smallest card.

I tried sorting manually but it became really ugly.

```
class Card {

    int worth;
    int num;
    Shapes shape_id;
    string name;
    string shape_name;
    string color;
    char symbol;
    string intToShape(int n);
    string intToColor(int n);
public:
    Card(int n, int shap);
    Card();
    int getNumOfCard() const;
    int getShapeOfCard() const;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Card& c);
    bool operator >(Card& other);
    bool operator <(Card& other);
    bool operator ==(Card& other);
    bool operator >=(Card& other);
    bool operator <=(Card& other);
    bool operator !=(Card& other);
};
```

c'tor of card:

```
Card::Card(int n, int shap) : num(n) , shape_id((Shapes)shap) {
    if (num>10 || num ==1) {
        switch (num) {
            case 11:
                name = "Jack" + intToShape(shap);
                symbol ='J';
                break;
            case 12:
                name = "Quin" + intToShape(shap);
                symbol = 'Q';
                break;
            case 13:
                name = "King" + intToShape(shap);
                symbol = 'K';
                break;
            case 1:
                name = "Ace" + intToShape(shap);
                symbol = 'A';
                break;
            default:
                string exceptionMessage("num > 13"); 
                throw (PckErr(exceptionMessage));
        }
    } else {
        symbol = 'N';
        name = std::to_string(num) + intToShape(shap);
    }
    if (num == 1) {
        worth = 14;  //ace worth 14!
    } else {
        worth = num;
    }
    shape = intToShape(shap);
    color = intToColor(shap);
}
```

the sorting part:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
    histogram[pCard[i]->getNumOfCard()]++;
    it = sorted_hand.insert(it,pCard[i]);
}
std::sort(sorted_hand.begin(), sorted_hand.end());
```

operators implementation:

```
bool Card::operator>(Card &other) {
    return this->worth > other.worth;
}

bool Card::operator<(Card &other) {
    return this->worth < other.worth;
}

... same for all
```

I expect a sorted vector of 5 cards to be:
2,3,4,5,1 
but the actual vecter is:
1,2,3,4,5.

Comment: Why do you expect `2,3,4,5,1`?  That doesn't look sorted

Comment: it is if it sorted by the operators

Comment: Try making a compare function that returns if the worth is less than the other worth, and add that as the last element for std::sort. std::sort(sorted_hand.begin(), sorted_hand.end(), compareFunction);

Comment: @GuySadoun Why?  You do `this->worth < other.worth` in your `operator <` so the smallest element will come first

Comment: to add the function as a parameter to sort function? @Jon Doe

Comment: but ace worth 14 @NathanOliver

Comment: @GuySadoun std::sort(beginning, ending, comparison_function_to_use)

Comment: @GuySadoun, can you include the code you use to construct the vector in your five-element test case?  Or even better, provide a [complete, compilable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @Jon Doe
thanks! it is working

Comment: Do you need pointers in `sorted_hand`? Prefer `std::vector<Card>` to `std::vector<Card *>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Jon Doe wrote

I wrote:

```
sort(sorted_hand.begin(), sorted_hand.end(), cardCompare);
```

while:

```
bool cardCompare(const Card* lh, const Card* rh) {
    return *lh <= *rh;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I can think of couple of ways to deal with the problem.

#### Solution 1

Assign the value 14 to ace.

#### Solution 2

Account for the special nature of the ace in the comparison function.

```
bool Card::operator<(Card &other) {
    int l = (this->worth == 1) ? 14 : this->worth;
    int r = (other.worth == 1) ? 14 : other.worth;
    return (l < r);
}
```

#### Suggestion for cleanup.

Change the function to work with `const` objects.

```
bool Card::operator<(Card const& other) const {
    int l = (this->worth == 1) ? 14 : this->worth;
    int r = (other.worth == 1) ? 14 : other.worth;
    return (l < r);
}
```